# Can't connection to WCF service via Xamarin.Android

Tags: c#, wcf, xamarin

I have an installed WCF service on my computer. And I can successfully connect to this service from Console app on windows, but if i use the same code on android it doesn't work.

```
using System;
using System.ServiceModel;
using Android.App;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;

namespace App1
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface ILogonService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string Logon(string appId);
    }

    [Activity(Label = "App1", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
            Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.MyButton);
            button.Click += ButtonOnClick;
        }

        private void ButtonOnClick(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            var binding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly);
            binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Basic;
            var endPointUri = new Uri(@"http://192.168.1.241/edo/Euphrates.svc/ILogonService-Basic");
            var factory = new ChannelFactory<ILogonService>(binding, new EndpointAddress(endPointUri));
            factory.Credentials.UserName.UserName = "test";
            factory.Credentials.UserName.Password = "test";
            ILogonService service = factory.CreateChannel();
            Console.WriteLine(service.Logon("test"));
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting this error:

> "System.Net.WebException: There was an error on processing web
>   request: Status code 401(Unauthorized): Unauthorized". 11-19
>   18:16:29.973 E/mono ( 1177): 11-19 18:16:29.973 E/mono ( 1177):
>   Unhandled Exception: 11-19 18:16:29.973 E/mono ( 1177):
>   System.Net.WebException: There was an error on processing web request:
>   Status code 401(Unauthorized): Unauthorized 11-19 18:16:29.973 E/mono
>   ( 1177): at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpRequestChannel+HttpChannelRequestAsyncResult.WaitEnd
>   () [0x00000] in :0 11-19 18:16:29.973 E/mono ( 1177): at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpRequestChannel.EndRequest
>   (IAsyncResult result) [0x00000] in :0 11-19 18:16:29.973 E/mono (
>   1177): at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpRequestChannel.Request
>   (System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
>   [0x00000] in :0 11-19 18:16:29.973 E/mono ( 1177): at
>   System.ServiceModel.MonoInternal.ClientRuntimeChannel.Request
>   (System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message msg, TimeSpan timeout) [0x00000]
>   in :0 11-19 18:16:29.973 E/mono ( 1177): at
>   System.ServiceModel.MonoInternal.ClientRuntimeChannel.Request
>   (System.ServiceModel.Description.OperationDescription od,
>   System.Object[] parameters) [0x00000] in :0 11-19 18:16:29.973 E/mono
>   ( 1177): at
>   System.ServiceModel.MonoInternal.ClientRuntimeChannel.DoProcess
>   (System.Reflection.MethodBase method, System.String operationName,
>   System.Object[] parameters) [0x00000] in :0 11-19 18:16:29.973 E/mono
>   ( 1177): at
>   System.ServiceModel.MonoInternal.ClientRuntimeChannel.Process
>   (System.Reflection.MethodBase method, System.String operationName,
>   System.Object[] parameters) [0x00000] in :0

How can I solve this problem? Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Have you enabled internet permissions in the manifest?

Comment: can you verify that the browser on your device/simulator can connect to the service endpoint?  I'm trying to eliminate the obvious connectivity issues

Comment: @Jason, I can connect to the service endpoint from browser on my device, but I can only get window to enter password and login, I can't check behaviour of working because from browser it always doesn't work

Comment: The exception is showing a status code of `401(Unauthorized)`. Are you sure the login credentials are correct? To me that says connectivity isn't an issue, instead its possibly an authentication problem.

Comment: credentials are correct, this code works on windows.